# SparQL: Replace subject URIs

Tags: sparql, fuseki

We have graphs containing oa:Annotations with certain properties. Since I am working on a local copy of the server, it would be useful to me to change these URIs to point to localhost. According to the book I read, I thought this should work, but it does not. It does not seem to change anything. Still, the server returns a 204, I am using the priting port and url (/update). So I definitely should be able to change things. There is no error message.

```
PREFIX oa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#>    

DELETE
{ GRAPH ?g {?oldIRI ?p ?o} }
INSERT
{ GRAPH ?g {?newIRI ?p ?o} }
WHERE
{
    GRAPH ?g {
        ?oldIRI a oa:Annotation .
        ?oldIRI ?p ?o .
    }

    BIND(
        CONCAT("http://localhost:80",
               SUBSTR( STR(?oldIRI),
                      34,
                      STRLEN(STR(?oldIRI)) ) 
        ) AS ?newIRI
    )

    FILTER(CONTAINS(?oldIRI, "part_of_old_url"))
}
```

Any idea why this does not have the effect I hoped for? The book I use as reference does have "recipies" to change properties and it's values, but there is no example changing the subjects, so I assume there is a more general problem?

### Update: using STR()

As suggested in the comments, I used `CONTAINS(STR(?oldIRI), "part_of_old_url")` to convert oldIRI to a string. I am not fully aware of all changes, but this is what I can say: (I have backups, no worry :D)

```
PREFIX oa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#>    

SELECT *
WHERE {
    GRAPH ?g {
        ?iri a oa:Annotation .
    }
} LIMIT 100
```

This query has zero results. It's a default query I often used to get some annotation uris for looking into things.

Comment: did you try without the `graph` keywords? Or do you have multiple graphs in your dataset? did you check via a `SELECT query whether `?oldIRI` and `?newIRI` have any bindings?

Comment: Try this: `FILTER contains(str(?oldIRI), "part_of_old_url"))`. Note that `?oldIRI` is replaces with `str(?oldIRI)` to turn the IRI into a string, which is necessary for `contains` to work in spec-compliant SPARQL stores.

Comment: I have several graphs, yes. But not many of them. I was told they to not have a spacial semantic meaning or so, so I never really looked into it. I assume that they only serve for data management. I used a select query to take a look at oldIRI and newIRI, and they are both fine (the URIs/IRIs I expect).

Using STR() changed things a little, but are not good yet. I'll update the description above.

Since I could not fix it until now, I chose another (less elegant) way of importing the data (export import kind of thing). Still, if you have any idea I'm open to it.